# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT error

Tags: java

```
class Talk {
        String[] values;
        try {
            InputStream is = getAssets().open("jdata.txt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(is);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));

            //Read File Line By Line
            while ((br.readLine()) != null) {
                 // Print the content on the console
                 strLine = strLine + br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) { //Catch exception if any
            System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        parse(strLine);
    }

    public void parse(String jsonLine) {
        Data data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonLine, Data.class);
        values[0]= data.toString();
        return;
    }
}
```

This is in `jdata.txt`:

```
"{" + "'users':'john' + "}"
```

This is my `Data.java`:

```
public class Data {
    public String users;
}
```

The error I get is:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 9
```

Can anyone explain to me what this error means and how to remove it?

EDIT:

I got the answer. These are the tweaks I had to do. First, change the String array to an array list.

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();
```

The next tweak was here:

```
strLine = currentLine;
              currentLine = br.readLine();
              //Read File Line By Line
              while (currentLine != null)   {
              // Print the content on the console

                  strLine = strLine + currentLine;
                  currentLine = br.readLine();
              }
```

The final tweak was here:

```
String val = data.toString();
values.add(val);
```

Certain parts of the code might be redundant but I will take care of that later.

Comment: your json is invalid this is correct json format `{"users": "john"
}`

Comment: @RanRag Have tried that. Didn't work. So changed it trying to get the right result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `readLine()` twice. The following causes a line to be read from the file and lost:

```
while ((br.readLine()) != null)   {
```

Change the loop to:

```
//Read File Line By Line
String currentLine = br.readLine();
while (currentLine != null)   {
     // Print the content on the console
     strLine = strLine + currentLine;
     currentLine = br.readLine();
}
```

Also, the contents of `jdata.txt` should be:

```
{"users":"john"}
```

without superfluous `+` or `"` characters.

Comment: Have you tried debugging it? Did you verify that the string you're passing to Gson is correct? Since Gson is open-source, you can debug into their code as well.

Comment: I've debugged. The code breaks after this line: Data data = new Gson().fromJson(jsonLine, Data.class);

Comment: And? Is the value of `jsonLine` correct? Have you tried stepping into `fromJson()`?

Comment: Ah! Wait a min! My bad. debugged again. Seems like my strLine just has nullnull.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the issue mentioned by @Eli.

This is the way of using `Gson Library` to parse json.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(jsonLine, Data.class);
System.out.println("users:" + data.getusers());
```

Now my Data.java file

```
public class Data {

public String users;

public String getusers() {
return users;
        }
```

Output =

> JSonString in jdata.txt = {"users": "john" }
>
> users : john   //after json parsing.